# Upanayanam Ritual information

Tags: gayatri-mantra, upanayanam

[Upanayanam ritual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanayana)

[Upanayanam ritual](https://www.itslife.in/festivals/upanayana)

[Gayatri Mantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayatri_Mantra)

I would like to know the following information and inputs from your end.

1 In case of those children who have lost their fathers before 8 years, who will perform the Upanayanam? Paternal Uncle, Maternal Uncle etc.

2 The Upanayanam ritual is only for Male and not female child. What are the reasons?

The Upanayanam ritual should be also for the female child as the Gayatri Mantra is uttered by the Father to his Son in the rituals. Similarly the Gayatri mantra from Father to his daughter. Similarly other common and customized  Upanayam rituals.

Comment: *..The Upanayanam ritual is only for Male and not female child.* - **Wrong, it is for both.**